# Class adapter pattern in Java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, adapter

```
interface movement{
    void jump();    //Jump is 1 Feet high
}

class mario(){
    void specificJump(int feet);   //Use variable feet to jump higher than 1 Feet
}

public class myAdapter extends mario implements movement{
    int feet;
    public void jump(){
        specificJump(feet); 
    }
}
```

movement is an interface with a single method that lets you jump 1 feet high.
mario is a class with a method specificJump(int feet) that lets you jump higher than 1 feet.
The implementation of myAdapter should work like this:

1. declare variable int feet
2. implement interface movement by declare and initialize public void jump()
3. use the function specificJump(feet) to jump to the height of int feet

So when trying to invoke jump() you actually will execute specificJump(feet).

Question: In order to execute specificJump(int feet) we first need to invoke jump().
However specificJump(int feet) needs a parameter, is it possible to just declare int feet, in myAdapter, like I did?
My issue is, how does someone get the int feet value in, when you have to call jump() with no parameter? (Using Class adapter pattern)

Comment: Presumably, a value of `feet` would be passed into the constructor of `myAdapter` or set via a setter method. What is `newMovement`? Should that be `myAdapter extends mario`?

Comment: Yes you're right thanks, just changed it.

Comment: Honestly the design doesn't seem to make any sense. If the contract of the interface defines the jump should not be higher than 1 feet high then it makes no sense to have implementations violate that contract. Furthermore, you can just override `jump` in `mario` and jump as high as mario needs to jump by default and then also have the parameterized `jump(int feet)` overload. Is that an assignment? What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

> void jump();    //Jump is 1 Feet high

Well if that's the interface contract the implementations shouldn't violate that
and allow jumps higher than 1 feet.

Therefore, you'd probably have:

```java
class MovableMario extends Mario implements Movement {
    @Override
    public void jump() {
        specificJump(1);
    }
}
```

Whichever clients need to jump a specific height can still use `mario.specificJump(feet)`.

Note that the design is very limiting, ideally the adapter would come in the form of decorator and delegate to an inner `Mario` instead.